# How to create dynamically an array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, malloc

I need to create a dynamic array of strings of same length. User first enters the string length, and then inputs as many strings as it wants. This is what I've done so far:

```
printf("Insert string length parameter:\n");
if (scanf("%d", &k) == 0) {
    printf("Error in parameter read!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
char buffer[k+1];
char **dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*)); //how to allocate enough pointers to str when n° of strs is unkn?

printf("Insert string sequence (allowed chars: a-Z, - e _):\n");
scanf("%s", buffer);
while(strcmp(buffer, "+exit") != 0) {
    if ((dictionary[words] = malloc(k * sizeof(char) + 1)) == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(dictionary[words], buffer);
    words++;
    scanf("%s", buffer);
}
for (i = 0; i < words; i++)
    printf("%s\n", dictionary[i]);
```

My idea is to create an array of pointers to each string. First user inputs the string, then I allocate memory for it and lastly I copy the string from the buffer to the allocated memory. The issue is that the memory behaves weirdly, I can for example set k to 3 and input a string 10 chars long and it would still work. However, if I enter some inputs of the correct length, the first ones get corrupted or something. For example, with k = 3, the series of inputs:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
+exit
```

results in:

```
­¶F☼
☻
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

Any suggestion on why this happens?
Thanks a lot to whoever helps me, it's really appreciated!

Comment: `char **dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*));` only allocates enough space for 1 pointer, so any `dictionary[words]` is out of bounds for `words > 0`. If you want to dynamically grow `dictionary` during runtime, you'll need to use [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)

Comment: **how to allocate enough pointers to str when n° of strs is unkn?** You don't. As @yano said, you use `realloc()` to increase the size as necessary. There are many tutorials on using `realloc()`.

Comment: thank you both for your suggestion, i didn't know this! i'll implement this right now

Comment: `k * sizeof(char) + 1` is conceptually wrong.  Should be `sizeof(char) * (k + 1)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica although in this case it doesn't cause errors, you are absolutely correct. thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @cliff2310 thank you, i have briefly read it yesterday. i hope this post meets all those requirements, i tried to include everything i could! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly noted in your code There is no way to allocate enough space for the string pointers if number of strings is not previously known.

You kind of have 4 options in this scenario

1. **Guess a max number of strings your user could input**

   Are there other constraints that limit how many strings your user can actually input? If so you can simply allocate the maximum amount of buffer required by doing something like

   ```c
   int MAX_STR = 100; // Could also be a #define somewhere
   char **dictionary = (char**) malloc(MAX_STR*sizeof(char*));
   ```

   This is kind of overkill and uses more memory than it needs. But in most modern systems where memory is not a tight constraint, this should be completely fine. And may even by more performant than using `realloc`
2. **Make the user tell you beforehand**

   This is kind of an obvious one. You add one more step to the UX and make the user tell you explicitly how much space you need. Then you can allocate accordingly

   ```c
   int num_str;
   printf("Enter number of strings: ");
   scanf("%d", &num_str); // Do the due diligence of checking if it is number
   char **dictionary = (char**) malloc(num_str*sizeof(char*));
   ```

   Of course this solution may not always be viable. For example if the 'user' themselves don't know the number.
3. **Reallocate on a need basis**

   As suggested in the comments, you can use `realloc()` to reallocate memory as you need

   It would go something like this:

   ```c
   int num_str = 0;
   char **dictionary = NULL;   // Don't initialize yet.
   while(strcmp(buffer, "+exit") != 0) {
       num_str += 1;
       dictionary = (char**) realloc(dictionary, num_str*sizeof(char*));
       ...
   }
   ```

   You can find more information about the `realloc()` function [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) (as mentioned in the comments)

   Lucrative as this method may sound, this kind of memory reallocation can be quite resource intensive on a system as everything may have to be copied over to the new location etc.
4. **Use a different data structure**

   You can use something like a linked list to store list of data whose size can grow or shrink on demand. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) for more info (or practically any other online guide)

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. i'm trying the realloc method as suggested, and it seems to work. however, i have to keep in mind memory efficiency as i have to respect a memory (and time) limit, so probably i'll have to change data structure as you mentioned. but for now, this works like charms! i wanted to first get a working version of the program and then optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

`char **dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*));` only allocates memory for 1 pointer.  Code needs a new approach to form the array of strings.

[@Parth K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73141638/2410359) outlines some alternatives.

Another is recursion.  Use the stack to store the strings until `"exit"` encountered.  Then allocate the array of string pointers.

```
// Untested illustrative code.
char** get_strings(size_t length_max, size_t count) {
  char buf[length_max + 3];  // plus 3 for \n \0 and extra detection
  printf("Insert string sequence (allowed chars: a-Z, - e _):\n");
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    size_t len = strlen(buf);
    if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') {
      buf[--len] = '\0';
    }
    if (len > length_max) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Line <%s> too long\n", buf);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (strcmp(buf, "+exit")) {
      char **list = get_strings(length_max, count + 1);
      if (list == NULL) {
        return NULL;
      }
      list[count] = strdup(buf);
      return list;
    }
  }
  char **list = malloc(sizeof *list * (count + 1));
  if (list == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  list[count] = NULL; // Mark last entry as NULL
  return list;
}
```

Usage

```
void foo() {
  char buf[40];
  printf("Insert string length parameter:\n");
  size_t k;
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && sscanf(buf, "%zu", &k) == 1) {
    char **list = get_strings(k, 0);
    if (list) {
      for (size_t i = 0; list[i]; i++) {
        printf("<%s>\n", list[i]);
        free(list[i]);
      }
      free(list);
    }
  }
}
```

- Tip do not use `scanf()` until you understand why it is bad.

GTG

Comment: thank you for your input, i will definitely look more into fgets and consider switching to it. one question, doesn't every recursive call occupy a new portion of memory for the new function iteration? i didn't really consider it since i have to keep memory usage below a certain threshold (i know i didn't mention this in my post but i planned to ask suggestions later if i got stuck with it), so i went with a linear approach right away.

Comment: @lumo126 Yes, every recursive call temporally uses a new portion of memory for `buf`.